# Using insert stored procedure with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

When I was learning to program originally, I was told that there was 3 possible outcomes; there was an error, it worked, or nothing happened.

I have the last the problem at the moment and there is no error message for me to submit.

Here is the windows form:

[image: screenshot of windows form]

The code for the buttons is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Basque
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private String strFirstName;
        private String strLastName;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            strFirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            strLastName = txtLastName.Text;
            int tempNo;
            AddNames(strFirstName, strLastName);
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        public void AddNames(String strFirstName, String strLastName)
        {
            String connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BasqueNames.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection oCON = new SqlConnection(connString);
            oCON.Open();

            SqlCommand oCMD = new SqlCommand();
            oCMD.Connection = oCON;
            oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCMD.CommandText = "usp_BasqueNames_Insert";

            oCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", strFirstName);
            oCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", strLastName);

            oCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oCON.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The schema for the database is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Names] 
(
    [Id]        INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    [LastName]  NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And the stored procedure is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_BasqueNames_Insert
    @First NCHAR(10),
    @Last NCHAR(10)
AS
    INSERT INTO Names(FirstName, LastName)
    VALUES (@First, @Last)

    RETURN @@identity
```

One thing that strikes me as odd is that when I start to debug the app, the database name in server explorer immediately has a red x on it.

Comment: The red x might be an error you need to address. Hover over it and see if a popup appears to give you more details.

Comment: Tip: `@@IDENTITY` can return surprising results if there are triggers present. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a better choice. (And learn about the `OUTPUT` clause for later.)

Comment: Are you sure that the btnSave_Click method is executing when the button is clicked?

Comment: What exactly is _not_ happening?  You clear the input text fields after you add the record - is the new record in the database?  You declare `int tempNo` but don't use it - is this meant to contain the new ID?  There is nothing in your code to catch exceptions or the results of failure and there is nothing to indicate success.  So what exactly is _not_ happening that you're expecting to happen?

Comment: To be exact what happening is that it cycles through the code, which I have debugged. It then gets to inserting the records into the table and nothing happens then. Could anyone recommend a good simple example with the appropriate try catches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? And please make sure you're trying to pass a value not more than 10 characters, since your nchar is just (10);

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddNames(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastName.Text);
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();
        }


        public void AddNames(string strFirstName, string strLastName)
        {
            String connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BasqueNames.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            using(SqlConnection oCON = new SqlConnection(connString))
           {
            SqlCommand oCMD = new SqlCommand("usp_BasqueNames_Insert",oCon);
    oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            oCMD.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.Nchar).Value = strFirstName;
            oCMD.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.Nchar).Value = strLastName;

            oCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the recommendations and support.

One thing had to change, I had to install and connect to sql express. I found that the Visual Studio Database was unreliable in Visual Studio to connect to.

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNames(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
    }


    public void AddNames(string strFirstName, string strLastName)
    {
        String connString = @"Data Source=ERNIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeatherDress;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";


        using(SqlConnection oCON = new SqlConnection(connString))
       {
        SqlCommand oCMD = new SqlCommand("usp_BasqueNames_Insert",oCon);
        oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        oCMD.Parameters.Add("@First", SqlDbType.Nchar).Value = strFirstName;
        oCMD.Parameters.Add("@Last", SqlDbType.Nchar).Value = strLastName;

        oCON.open();
        oCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        oCON.close();
        }
    }
```